# Is there a licence issue using the "All authorised users" type of permission group?

Tags: permissions, licence, cal

Is there a licence issue using the "All authorised users" type of permission group?

Does it require extra CALs or is it just a synonym that doesn't matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All authenticated users will grant everyone with a valid username/AD account access to the site. If you have CALs for everyone in your company, then there won't be an issue.  If you only have a few CALs for SP access for a select group of users and open it up to everyone, you would be in violation of the licensing terms should you get audited.

Comment: I was asking because this group is in MySites for UPS permissions with social tagging. However if you have permissions for AD users this means that this "All authorised users" group is then valid?